# Pass Class as Parameter in Generic Function

Tags: c#

I'm using this neat [classes](https://exceptionnotfound.net/mapping-datatables-and-datarows-to-objects-in-csharp-and-net-using-reflection/) to map data tables from a MySQL database into objects.
Now I would like to write a generic function to return a list for a variety of different classes so I could call:

```
List<Person> persons = ReadDataTable<Person>();
List<Car> persons = ReadDataTable<Car>();
```

and many more classes.

But I don't unterstand how to create the object DataNamesMapper in my generic function:

```
public List<T> ReadDataTable<T>()
{   
  List<T> parsedObjects = new List<T>();       
  DataNamesMapper<typeof(T)> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<typeof(T)> (); //<- error
  DataNamesMapper<Person> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<Person> (); //<- no error, non-generic
  //...query data, map and fill list
  return parsedObjects;
}
```

DataMapper is defined:

```
public class DataNamesMapper<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try `DataNamesMapper<T>` instead of `DataNamesMapper<typeof(T)>`

Comment: @AleksAndreev you should post that as an answer, IMO. Short but correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataNamesMapper` is open type. To make it closed to `T` you need to  use this syntax:

```
DataNamesMapper<T> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<T>();
```

Comment: This gives me the error:   The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DataNamesMapper<TEntity>'

Comment: @flexo I think it because you defined your `ReadDataTable<T>` method without constraint, but `DataNamesMapper` has 2: `class, new()`. So add a `where` clause to your ReadDataTable declaration

Comment: Ahh.. Did not understand that! Thank you very much for you help!